# Windows 10 get input from Hardware input 3

Tags: windows, audio, microphone

I have a focusrite scarlett 18i8 and usually have my mic plugged into input number 3. Is there a way to get arbitrary applications (eg. discord) to use that channel as the mic input.

I usually use linux with JACK Audio where you can route audio from anywhere to anywhere. I tried installing JACK for windows but it doesn't see all of the audio inputs either.

I don't need all of the power of jack audio for windows but it would be nice if I didn't have to adjust mic cables whenever I want to play some game I can't make run on linux.

I am running Windows 10 Home Edition on an HP envy 15 laptop with a focusrite scarlett 18i8 audio interface.

Comment: This is dependent on the drivers for the 18i8. If the driver exposes the various inputs as individual devices, then it's up to your application (e.g. discord) to enumerate those devices and offer them to you. The Windows sound applet would also let you select any of them as your default "recording" device. If the 18i8's drivers don't do that then there is nothing that any app can do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to use [Jack Audio](http://jackaudio.org/faq/jack_on_windows.html) and [VB audio ASIO Bridge](https://www.vb-audio.com/Cable/).
Jack has JackRouter an ASIO driver that allows ASIO devices to connect to jack. ASIO bridge connects to an ASIO device and routes it to a normal windows device. This allows jack to route any input on my interface to a non-ASIO compatible device.